# How would these functions differ given the following property?

Tags: limits, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

Function a: $|x−1|<0.5=>|a(x)−3|<2$ and that the limit of this function as x approaches 1 exists.

Function b: $0<|x−1|<0.5=>|b(x)−3|<2$ and that the limit of this function as x approaches 1 exists.

Does the $0<$ in function b make the function any different from function a? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that $b(x)$ does not need to be defined at $x=1$ or if it is it can be anything.  As an example, let $c(x)=x+2$.  This clearly satisfies the requirement for $a$.  Let $$d(x)=\begin {cases} x+2& x \neq 1\\1000&x=1 \end {cases}$$  It satisfies the requirement for $b$, but fails the requirement for $a$.

Comment: Does this mean that a(x) is continuous when x = 1?

Comment: No, but it has to be somewhat close to $3$.  How close?

Comment: Within 2 units?

Comment: That is correct.  We are not given that $\lim_{x \to 1} a(x)=3$, just that the limit exists.  It could be anything in the range $[1,5]$.  We are separately guaranteed that $|a(1)-3| \lt 2$ so $a(1)$ can be anything in the range $(1,5)$ but not the endpoints.

Comment: Sorry for the late question but why is the range [1, 5] and not (1, 5)?

Comment: You are correct, as the less than signs are strict the range is $(1,5)$

Comment: Im confused, you wrote "It could be anything in the range [1,5]." Or are you saying that you meant (1, 5).

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 1} a(x)$  could be anything in the range $[1,5]$.  The value of $a(1)$ has to be in the range $(1,5)$.  There is no requirement that the function be continuous, so $a(1)$ may be different from the limit.